# error document is closed when try to display page number on pdf file exported?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I worked on asp.net core razor page I face issue when display page

number at the end of every page from exported pdf .

I get error

```
iText.Kernel.Exceptions.PdfException: 'Document was closed. It is impossible to execute action.'
```

this error generated on line

`int pageCount = pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages();`

if i have pdf contain 3 pages then it will display at end of every page
on first page page 1  and second page page 2 third page page 3 on bottom of pages

i get error on iText.Kernel.Exceptions.PdfException: 'Document was closed. It is impossible to execute action.' this error generating on line

```
`int pageCount = pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages();`
```

code what i try

```
 ` using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pdfHtml)))
 {
     ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(byteArrayOutputStream);
     PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
     pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());

     HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(stream, pdfDocument);
     int pageCount = pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages();
     for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
     {
         Document doc = new Document(pdfDocument);
         doc.ShowTextAligned(new Paragraph("Page " + i + " of " + pageCount),
             pdfDocument.GetDefaultPageSize().GetWidth() - 50, 30, i, TextAlignment.RIGHT, VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM, 0);
     }

     pdfDocument.Close();
     return File(byteArrayOutputStream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "AssetTaggingDetails.pdf");
 }`
```

Comment: Which PDF converter package you have used ? Could you please share its name?

Comment: package used iText7